# Is it possible to write a generic application to interface with Zigbee USB dongles of different manufacturers?

Tags: usb, zigbee, dongle

I want to write an application which can work on a PC OS like Windows or Linux and interact with a Zigbee Dongle acting as a coordinator which interacts with other Zigbee devices. The application should be able to detect new devices and services added on the Zigbee Network and also should be able to send commands to the Zigbee Network.

I have below doubts in this regard:

(a) Is it possible to write a generic application which can work with USB dongles of all manufacturers?

(b) While googling, I found that most Zigbee USB dongle's seem to support AT Command mode & API mode. Where can more details be found on API mode?

(c) The AT commands seems to be different for different Zigbee dongles. Is there a standard set of AT Commands?

(d) Is it possible to frame packets based on Standard Zigbee Application Layer Formats and send it to the USB dongle?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. You will need a different firmware for each USB dongle (eg each manufacturer MCU) that can "tunnel" ZigBee commands, and then use a single application. All the "AT" commands stuff is *not* ZigBee standard, it's just "let's use a known protocol on top of ZigBee, and use ZigBee as network layer".
Depending on the set of ZigBee commands you are interest into (HA, SE, LLK, common ZCL) this may or may not be possible. For sure SE is not, you will need to pay for a security certificate if you wish to be a SE network coordinator.

Comment: Thanks. How the API mode? Does it allow us feed Zigbee based directly to the dongle?

Comment: I think API mode exists only in Digi's ZigBee/XBee modules.